# Selection sort returning undefined

Tags: javascript, algorithm, ecmascript-6

I am trying to implement the Selection sort algorithm in Javascript but it's returning undefinded. I tried to have a thorough look plenty of times but can't figure out the error.

Here's my code:

```
const selectionSort = (arr) => {
  let smallest;
  let len = arr.length;
  for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    smallest = i;
    for (j = i + 1; j < len; j++) {
      if (arr[smallest] > arr[j]) {
        smallest = j;
      }
    }

    let temp = arr[i];
    arr[i] = arr[smallest];
    arr[smallest] = temp;
  }
  return smallest;
};
console.log(selectionSort[(3, 2, 4, 1)]);
```

Comment: You have switched the square and round brackets after your call to `selectionSort()`

Answer (score 1):

Here I think you are passing it wrong

```
console.log(selectionSort([3, 2, 4, 1]));
```

Function takes array as input.

```js
const selectionSort = (arr) => {
    let smallest;
    let len = arr.length;
    for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      smallest = i;
      for (j = i + 1; j < len; j++) {
        if (arr[smallest] > arr[j]) {
          smallest = j;
        }
      }
  
      let temp = arr[i];
      arr[i] = arr[smallest];
      arr[smallest] = temp;
    }
    return arr;   //return array here if you want full array
  };
  console.log(selectionSort([3, 2, 4, 1]));
```

Comment: Thanks, made a typo error. And was returning the smallest instead of the array. Thank you for the help, really appreciate it.